# Get directed path in python networkx

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, networkx

I want to get only the directed path between two nodes in directed G using networkx.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
G=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(NUMBER_OF_NODES,PPROB_OF_EDGE,True)
nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,u, v) #u and v are some nodes in G
```

This will return a path even if edges list of G only have following entries

```
[(u,w),(v,w)]
```

My goal is to get the directed path only. Is there a way in networkx to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
G=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(NUMBER_OF_NODES,PPROB_OF_EDGE,True)
```

you end up with an undirected graph.  Thus the edge `(u,w)` is an undirected edge --- there is no difference between `(u,w)` and `(w,u)`.  It doesn't make sense to talk about a "directed path".

I believe you want the graph to be directed, and that is what your `True` argument at the end is.  But because of the order that `nx.fast_gnp_random_graph` takes its optional arguments, this isn't what you're doing.  Instead you should say

```
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(NUMBER_OF_NODES, PROB_OF_EDGE, directed=True)
```

(and as a note, I think generally capital letters are frowned upon in python code).

Comment: Thanks.  This code snippet is a part of a larger code and I am using the capital letters to represent global variable :)